# Terminology for invariant factors of quotient module over PID

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, terminology, principal-ideal-domains, smith-normal-form

Let $A$ be a PID, $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module and $N$ a submodule. By the structure theorem of finitely generated modules or by Smith normal form, $M/N \cong \prod A/(a_i)$ for certain $a_i \in A$.

The $(a_i)$ are called invariant factors or elementary divisors of $M/N$.

I feel like there exists a noun xxx that allows me to say "Let $(a_i)$ be the xxx of $N$ in $M$." Is there such a word?

Comment: Aren't invariant factors/elementary divisors precisely those nouns?

Comment: @mrtaurho I'm not sure if I've ever read "invariant factors of N *in M*"

Comment: Me neither but it sounds like a reasonable expression conveying exactly what you want (don't you think?).

Comment: Ok, cool! Thanks for your opinion. I'll go ahead and use it.

Answer (score 0):

In

Macdonald, I.G. *Symmetric functions and Hall Polynomials*, §II.1, page 180.

$(a_i)$ is called the cotype of $N$ in $M$.

Comment: This is quite an ad-hoc terminology. I'd go for the invariant factors of N in M. I guess Jacobson used it in Basic Algebra I. In any case it sounds right.